# How to configure sqlalchemy to throw error messages in english?

Tags: localization, internationalization, sqlalchemy

Sqlalchemy is throwing me error messages in french On my french-configured linux (ubuntu) lappy. What do I have to do to have those error messages in english ?

PS :

```
(my-coriolis)chaouche@jogger:~/$ echo $LANG
en_US.utf8
(my-coriolis)chaouche@jogger:~/$
```

Answer (score 0):

LC_ALL should be set to en_US.UTF-8 too.

Comment: Sorry for not giving feedback. As I moved on to another subject @work not involving sqla directly I didn't try your solution yet. But looking at the locale man page it seems that LC_ALL will set all of the locale-related env variables to the value I give to it. If sqlalchemy is locale-aware, it should get that value.